# Create label for two column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with two column of data. Now i want to make a label for two column, like the picture bellow:
[image]

Because two column donot have the same value so cant use groupby. I just only want add the label AAA like that. So, how to do it? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need create `MultiIndex` in columns, simpliest is:

```
df.columns = [['AAA'] * len(df.columns), df.columns]
```

It is similar as [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html), also is possible add names parameter:

```
n = ['a','b']
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['AAA'] * len(df.columns), df.columns], names=n)
```

Answer (score 5):

reassign to the `columns` attribute with an newly constructed `pd.MultiIndex`

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['AAA'], df.columns.tolist()])
```

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(1, ['hostname', 'tmserver'], ['value', 'time'])
print(df)

          value  time
hostname      1     1
tmserver      1     1
```

Then

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['AAA'], df.columns.tolist()])

print(df)

           AAA     
         value time
hostname     1    1
tmserver     1    1
```